# rake aborted! Permission denied - rsa_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to run db:migrate

keep getting rake aborted

==  CreateLocalKeys: migrating ================================================
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Permission denied - rsa_key

I can't find anything about this

any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Are you accessing your DB over an SSH tunnel?  Or perhaps installed a new plugin/gem prior to this migration?

Comment: Are you able to post the source of the migration?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to install [Insoshi](http://github.com/insoshi/insoshi)?  If so, I would assume the user account running the migration does not have write access to the local filesystem.  The particular migration writes keys to a local file as seen here: http://github.com/insoshi/insoshi/blob/master/db/migrate/012_create_local_keys.rb

I'm assuming your user account needs write access in your rails root directory (at a minimum).  Probably a little chown/chmod love will help.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo rake db:migrate
```

First thing I can think of. But I've never had a problem running db:migrate.